# Recursively structure array of objects : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render an array as a nested tree which can go up-to n levels. Basically I have an JSX that depicts parent and children. Based on if the node is parent or child , I need to render the tree by attaching classname.

JSX of the parent looks like:

```
  <div className="level-0 group">
        <div className="details-holder">
           <span className="item-text">{name}</span>
        </div>
  </div>
```

JSX of the children look like:

```
 <div className="level-1 leaf">
           <span className="line" />
           <div className="details-holder">
               <span className="item-text">{name}</span>
           </div>
  </div>

  <div className="level-2 leaf">
           <span className="line" />
           <div className="details-holder">
               <span className="item-text">{name}</span>
           </div>
  </div>
```

These JSX needs to rendered dynamically based on the array of the objects with the follolwing structure

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
        "className": "level-0 group",
        "children": [{
            "name": "abc.xyz",
            "className": "level-1 leaf",
            "children": [{
                "className": "level-2 leaf",
                "name": "abc.xyz.pqr",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
}]
```

So ideally the parent should have `level-0 group` class, children `level-1 leaf` , grandchildren `level-2 leaf` and so on.

Code that I tried is below, but how would I do it dynamically

```
return(
  { data.map(item => {
     <>
       <div className=`${item.className}`>
        <div className="details-holder">
           <span className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
        </div>
       </div>
 
       <div className={`${item[0].children[0].className`}>
           <span className="line" />
           <div className="details-holder">
               <span className="item-text">{item[0].children[0].name}</span>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div className={`${item[0].children[1].className`}>
           <span className="line" />
           <div className="details-holder">
               <span className="item-text">{item[0].children[1].name}</span>
           </div>
       </div>
     </>
    }
  }
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this if it's work for you. It more in modular form which help you to update the parent and child HTML fragment separately.

```
const Parent = (item) => (
  <div className={`${item.className}`}>
    <div className="details-holder">
      <span className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const Child = (item) => (
  <div className={`${item.className}`}>
    <span className="line" />
    <div className="details-holder">
      <span className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
    </div>
    {item.children.map((ch) => (
      <Child {...ch} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <>
          <Parent {...item} />
          {item.children.map((ch) => (
            <Child {...ch} />
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple if you implement the recursion inside the component. Just pass children as data into the same component calling itself.

```
const Tree = (props) => {

  return <>
    {
    props.data.map((item) => {

      return <div className = {item.className} > {
          (props.level !== 0) && < span className = "line" />
        } <div className = "details-holder" >
        <span className = "item-text" > {name} </span> </div> {
          props.data.children.map(() => <Tree data={item.children} level={props.level + 1} > )
        } </div>
      })
  
    }
  </>

}


<Tree data={data} level={0} />
```

Comment: `< span className = "line" />` shoul be present only for children

Comment: @li87 Corrected the code by negation.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer

Comment: @li97 So mark it as an answer or vote it up. These things matter.